Problems adding APKs in an AOSP build
I added my app folder in /packages/apps/'folder app'. Inside my 'folder app' I have my_app.apk and android.mk:
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests

LOCAL_MODULE := 'folder app'

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := my_app.apk

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS

LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

After, I added the reference of the package in /build/target/product/handheld_product.mk:
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    Browser2 \
    Camera2 \
    LatinIME \
    Launcher3QuickStep \
    Music \
    'folder app' \
    OneTimeInitializer \
    Provision \
    Settings \
    SettingsIntelligence \
    SystemUI \
    StorageManager \
    WallpaperCropper \
    frameworks-base-overlays

PRODUCT_PACKAGES_DEBUG += \
    frameworks-base-overlays-debug

When I start the system, it doesn't appear the new app.

Make sure to check in installed-files.json in the out directory that the APK has been added as a part of the build?

In fact, the apk hasn't been added to installed-files.json, how do I do that ?

Problem might be LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests, try using optional instead of tests.

Two things to look at:

To auto-generate makefile for apk, you can this tool instead of doing it manually, and it'll generate the bare minimum configs needed https://github.com/northbright/genandroidmk
Verify if handheld_product.mk is being included or not. Usually modifications are done on you actual product makefile in device/ folder instead of the global ones on build/


Also worth checking is that, if you replace the module name spaces, and correct the name in the list and include it without the '' quotation marks?
